# How can I get all the index of all the NaNs of a list?

Tags: python, numpy, nan

I am trying to make a list with the index of all `NaNs` in the list `a`.

The problem is that the list `ind` doesn't fill with anything. It works if instead of `NaN`, I put a random string like `c`.

```py
import numpy as np

a=[1, 2, 3, 4, np.nan, np.nan, 2, np.nan]

ind=[]
for i in range(0,len(a)):

    if a[i]==float("NaN"):
        ind.append(i)
print ind
```

Comment: instead of a[i]=float("NaN") it sould be np.nan, but I think it's the same

Comment: `np.nan` does not equal `np.nan`, nor does it equal `float('nan')`.  Use `np.flatnonzero(np.isnan(a))`

Comment: where are the nan's? np.where(np.isnan(a))[0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using NumPy, you should really start using arrays, and get out of the habit of manually looping at Python level. Manual loops are typically about 100 times slower than letting NumPy handle things, and lists of floats take about 4 times the memory of an array.

In this case, NumPy can give you an array of NaN indices quite simply:

```
ind = numpy.where(numpy.isnan(a))[0]
```

[`numpy.isnan`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html) gives an array of booleans telling which elements of `a` are NaN. [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) gives an array of indices of `True` elements, but wrapped in a 1-element tuple for consistency with the behavior on multidimensional arrays, so `[0]` extracts the array from the tuple.

This works when `a` is a list, but you should really use arrays.

---

Your attempt fails because NaN values aren't equal to each other or themselves:

```
>>> numpy.nan == numpy.nan
False
>>> numpy.nan == float('nan')
False
```

NaN was designed this way for algorithmic convenience, to make `x != x` a simple check for NaN values in environments where producing a NaN to compare against is awkward, and because NaNs have a rarely-used *payload* component that may be different between different NaNs.

---

The other answer recommends an `is numpy.nan` test, but this is buggy and unreliable. It only works if your NaNs happen to be the specific object `numpy.nan`, which is rarely the case:

```
>>> float('nan') is numpy.nan
False
>>> numpy.float64(0)/0 is numpy.nan
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
False
>>> numpy.array([numpy.nan])[0] is numpy.nan
False
```

Rely on `is numpy.nan` checks, and they *will* bite you.

Answer (score 1):

Use np.nan for comparison

```
import numpy as np

a=[1,2,3,4,np.nan,np.nan,2,np.nan]

ind=[]
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    if a[i] is np.nan:
        ind.append(i)
print ind
```

Output

```
[4, 5, 7]
```

Using List Comprehension:

```
[x  for x in range(0,len(a)) if a[x] is np.nan]
```

Alternatively, if you have built the array using numpy functions, then use `np.isnan(a[i])` for comparison.

Comment: This only works because you're building a list containing a single np.nan object yourself.  Numpy itself doesn't promise to return a single NaN object: for example, `np.array([np.nan])[0] is np.nan` gives False for me, and `[id(x) for x in np.array([np.nan, np.nan])]` returns two distinct values.

Comment: @DSM You can use `np.isnan(np.array([np.nan])[0])` for it. Thanks for bringing this point.