# Inconsistent behavior of nans in Python numpy / pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nan

When I was working on some set operations in Python, using `numpy` and `pandas` I came across a strange phenomenon, which, I would state, results in an inconsistency in `nan`s handling.

Let's assume that we have a very simple situation with sets as our points of interest:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a = {1, 2, 3, np.nan}
b = {1, 2, 4, np.nan}

print(a - b)
```

Out:

```
{3}
```

This is perfectly fine and we would expect it to be so, but let us continue with somewhat more complicated example, where `pandas` series / data frame is included:

```
series = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, np.nan, 1, 2, 3])
d = set(series)
print(d)
```

Out:

```
{nan, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0}
```

Once again, perfectly fine. Though, when we call:

```
print(d - b)  # the same applies to a single column of a data frame in place of a series
```

the result is (quite unexpectedly to me):

```
{nan, 3.0}
```

There is still a `nan` value in the output.

I do understand that when we create the `series` variable all of the input values are cast under the hood to a `float64` format, including the `nan` value.

```
type(series.iloc[3])
```

Out:

```
numpy.float64
```

Whereas the type of a freely created `np.nan` is just `float`. Of course, the `np.isnan()` function in both cases returns `True`. I still see it though as an inconsistency, because I would assume that all basic Python operations (to which set operations undoubtedly belong) will be treating `nan`s in a similar manner to the numbers. Even if the same type conversion as in case of `nan`s was applied to the numbers in the sets (in pure Python they are `int`s, whereas in `pandas` series they are `float`s), set operations still consider them as the same entities and remove values adequately. `nan` is supposed to be also (quasi-)numeric and yet is handled differently. Is this a feature, a bug or an acknowledged situation which cannot be for some reason resolved?

Python version: 3.6.6.
Numpy version: 1.16.2.
Pandas version: 0.24.2.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942303/how-does-a-python-set-check-if-two-objects-are-equal-what-methods-does-an-o My Google-fu could not find how Python implements the set difference exactly. Testing (in Python 2.7) shows it is neither `==` (because `{np.nan} - {np.nan}` returns an empty set) nor `is` (ditto for `{1.0} - {1}`).

Comment: Thanks @Leporello, this is an important factor for this question (determination of equality of objects), but there is also another side to this inquiry: whether the observed phenomenon is desired (if yes - in what situations is it beneficial) or rather erroneous. Still though, very useful observation!

Comment: On equality of nan's https://stackoverflow.com/a/56193097/901925

Comment: `float('nan')` and `np.nan` are different objects (don't match with `is`), even though both are `float` and satisfy `np.isnan`.  And being `nan` they aren't `==`.  So a `set` will contain both.  More generally, using `set` with floats is unreliable.

Comment: Well, that was actually my point. Thanks to your comments I understand what's behind the phenomenon I am asking about, but one thing remains: the answer to the question whether that is actually consistent with the rest of the pythonic world, as in my view - it isn't. I would expect the same behavior from `nan`s as from `float`s (as `nan`s are quasi-numeric) and currently I do not see any consistency in that.